# Overlapping data on columns in a ggplot facet grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, facet-grid

Thanks in advance for humoring a complete newbie to R. I'm working with some data from the GSS for an online class, and I've created a ggplot facet grid. I'm sure I've done this a super awkward, long way, but I'm trying to get these data points to not overlap each other, but be centered on the columns.

Here's what I've got so far:

I've created a new dataset from the GSS with the variables 'conpress', 'sex', and 'news' -- which refer to the confidence in the press, gender and how often someone reads a newspaper. I wanted to get the percentages, not the counts, which is why I did the ..count..stuff.

```
gss_press_full <- gss %>% select (conpress, news, sex)

gss_press_clean <-na.omit(gss_press_full)


ggplot(gss_press_clean, aes(x = conpress, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = sex)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), position = position_dodge()) + facet_grid(news~.) +
    geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = round((..count..)/sum(..count..), 2)), stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
    labs(title = "Newspaper readership and Press confidence", y = "Percent", x = "Levels of confidence in the Press")
```

I have been googling for far too long and can't seem to find a way to adjust these labels atop the columns. It seems to be especially tricky since my y variable is being calculated in my ggplot creation, but again, like a complete novice, that was how I cobbled my way to the output. If someone has help on how to streamline this process, I'd appreciate that too!

( I hope I've included enough code to be helpful!)

Again, thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you edit your post to include data i.e `dput(gss_press_clean)`. Also do you have to do this within `ggplot` only or you are ok manipulating data before plotting.

Comment: Ronak, thanks for writing back. I've been trying all morning to figure out dput, but am struggling with that too. (again SUPER novice here.) I watched this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rn6BgT15yIs  but it didn't really help because when I tried the dput, I didn't get the "structure" coding he was mentioning. All I got was lines and lines of this:
`57058` = 57058L, `57059` = 57059L, `57061` = 57061L), class = "omit"), row.names = 4602:4626, class = "data.frame") 
Is this because I'm working with 3 categorical variables? I'm so confused!

Comment: `dput` is a way to share data with us so we can copy paste them into our session. Here is the post which explains that in detail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 If the data is too big maybe you can share only first 10 lines  i.e `dput(head(gss_press_clean, 10))`